# Рекурсивный вызов в Python проход по List

Tags: python, рекурсия

Необходимо обойти дерево каталогов (уже сформированное) - у каждого каталога есть название.

пример дерева:

```
Каталог1---Каталог2---Каталог3
               |------Каталог4
```

В результате нужно сделать что-то вроде хлебных крошек - сохранить полные пути типа 
Каталог1 -> Каталог2 -> Каталог3
Каталог1 -> Каталог2 -> Каталог4  и т.д.

Решил проходить рекурсией вот что получилось:

```
def __create_objects(folder,text):
text=text+folder['title']+"->"
for child in folder['children']:
    __create_objects(folder['children'][child], text)
```

Это **работает**, но кроме текста возникла необходимость записывать не текст а объекты в лист вида: [Каталог1, Каталог2, Каталог3], [Каталог1, Каталог2, Каталог4]. Вот тут и начались проблемы - написал так:

```
def __create_objects(folder,obj):
obj.append(folder)
for child in folder['children']:
    __create_objects(folder['children'][child], obj)
```

Теперь вывод происходит так:
[Каталог1, Каталог2, Каталог3, Каталог4]

Не пойму где ошибка.

**UPD**

[image: Вид дерева каталогов - такой, какой приходит]

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)?

Comment: Проблема в том, что os.walk принимает на вход путь в виде строки, а у меня уже готовая структура - список, где элементами являются дочерние директории (тоже списки) и т.д. Можно ли как-то скормить os.walk эту структуру?

Comment: Вы можете привести пример готового списка (вашего "дерева") в его оригинальном виде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка у вас состоит в том что вы изменяете один и тот же список (один и тот же объект) с помощью `append()`

Код со строками "работает" потому что строки неизменяемы в Питоне. Поэтому каждый раз новая строка у вас создаётся. Хотя функции ничего не возвращают, поэтому **код как он написан в вопросе ничего не делает.**

Чтобы сделать код аналогичным случаю со строками, можете кортеж вместо списка использовать, чтобы исключить возможность что вы случайно измените одну и ту же последовательность.

Минимальное изменение вашего кода, которое "работает":

```
def __create_objects(folder,obj):
    obj = obj + (folder,)
    for child in folder['children']:
        __create_objects(folder['children'][child], obj)
```

Можно код изменить, чтобы он возвращал что-нибудь:

```
def walk(tree, path=()):
    path = path + (tree['name'],)
    yield path
    for child in tree['children']:
        yield from walk(child, path)
```

Пример:

```
tree = {
    'name': 'Folder 1',
    'children': [
        {'name': 'Folder 2',
         'children': [
              {'name': 'Folder 3',
                'children': []},
              {'name': 'Folder 4',
                'children': []}]}]}

for path in walk(tree):
    print(*path)
```

#### Вывод

```
Folder 1
Folder 1 Folder 2
Folder 1 Folder 2 Folder 3
Folder 1 Folder 2 Folder 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

class Folders(dict):
    def __init__(self, folder: str, level=0):
        self.name = folder
        self.files = []
        print(self.name, level)

        self.set_folder(level + 1)

    def set_folder(self, level):
        for ob in os.listdir(self.name):
            obj = os.path.join(self.name, ob)

            if os.path.isfile(obj):
                self.files.append(obj)
            else: self[obj] = Folders(obj, level)

Folders(os.getcwd())
```